Solaris 10 find exclude directory 'oracle'
find . -type f -size +390625 -prune '/oracle' -exec ls -lh {} \;
find: bad option /oracle

Just want to find all large files on system but exclude /oracle.
Thanks in advance.

The -prune doesn't take an argument.
Instead, when invoked for the path currently being considered, it causes find not to descend into it.
Since the directory you ask find to find files into is ., the path of any file can never be /oracle. At best, it can be ./oracle if you run that command whilst the current working directory is /.
Then, if you want to prune ./oracle, the syntax should be:
find . -path ./oracle -prune -o -type f -size +390625 -exec ls -ldh {} +

That is, only call -prune when the path is ./oracle, and for any other file check for type and size and execute ls if matching.
Because of the precedence rules between -o (or) and -a (and; implied when omitted between two predicates), that is actually interpreted as:
find . '(' -path ./oracle -a -prune ')' -o \
       '(' -type f -a -size +390625 -a -exec ls -ldh {} + ')'

Beware that if you omit the -exec..., then the default action is -print but applied to the whole expression as if you had written:
find . '(' \
          '(' -path ./oracle -a -prune ')' -o \
          '(' -type f -a -size +390625 ')' \
       ')' -print

So ./oracle would also be printed (-prune always returns true). So you would want an explicit -print in that case:
find . -path ./oracle -prune -o -type f -size +390625 -print

For that to be interpreted as:
find . '(' -path ./oracle -a -prune ')' -o \
       '(' -type f -a -size +390625 -a -print ')'

Also note that -size +390625 matches on files whose apparent size rounded up to an integer number of 512-byte units is strictly greater than 390625, so files that are 390625 * 512 + 1 = 200000001 bytes large or larger. You can also do -size +200000000c for that which more easily reads as larger than 200MB and works for sizes that are not necessarily multiples of 512.

Edit. as you found out, Solaris 10's find doesn't support -path. -path is originally from BSD, added in 1991, and added soon after in GNU find (3.6 from 1992), but by that time SunOS was already forgoing its BSD origin as SunOS 5 (rebranded as Solaris 2) would be based on SVR4 instead.
-path is now a standard predicate of find, but has "only" been made standard in POSIX in the 2008 edition.
Solaris 11.4's find does support it, but not even that of 11.3. Solaris 11.4 is registered as compliant to the 2008 edition (SUSv4), Solaris 10 and earlier versions of Solaris 11 to the 2004 edition only (SUSv3).
So on those systems, if you need to do comparison on the full path, you need to resort to things like -exec test ./oracle = {} ';' instead, which you can make less prohibitively expensive by doing -name oracle -type d -exec test ./oracle = {} ';' to avoid running one test command for every file but only for the ones named oracle and that are of type directory, so:
find . -name oracle -type d -exec test ./oracle = {} ';' -prune -o \
       -type f -size +390625 -exec ls -ldh {} +

You'll actually find that the POSIX rationale for adding -path was for that exact purpose. Quoted from the corresponding enhancement request from 2006:

Problem:
There is currently no standard way to instruct the find utility not
to  descend into one or more specific directories.  (In the general
case,  that is; it can be done in specific cases such as when the
directory  has a unique basename that can be matched using -name, or
when all  directories that are mount points are to be skipped.)
In order to work around this omission, portable applications have to
post-process the output of find with other tools such as grep.  This
can be very inefficient if the directory to be skipped is deep, or
produce unwanted "permission denied" messages if the user does not
have read or search permission for some directories below it, or be
slowed by having to access slow speed removable media that could have
been skipped.
The FreeBSD, GNU, HP-UX and MacOS X versions of find, and possibly
others, have a -path primary that can be used (with -prune) for this
purpose.  I feel this would be a worthwhile addition to the standard.

Though as shown above one does not have to post-process the output,  as it's always possible to run a command such as test for equality comparison or awk for regexp matching or sh with a case statement for shell pattern matching to do something equivalent (though at a much much higher cost in terms of performance).
-path "$pattern" can be written -exec sh -c 'case $1 in ($2) true;; (*) false;; esac' sh {} "$pattern" ';' (with the caveat as usual that on Solaris 10, to get a standard compliant sh, you need /usr/xpg4/bin to be ahead of /bin in $PATH as /bin/sh was still an ancient Bourne shell then; replaced with ksh93 in Solaris 11)

solaris find doesn't use -path

@NoRelocation, Solaris 11 at least would as -path has been in POSIX since the 2008 edition.  If Solaris 10 doesn't have it, you can use -name oracle -exec test {} = ./oracle ';' as an alternative.

@NoRelocation, see edit for further detail. I didn't think we would still see a find without -path in 2024.
